# Python: How to extract specific row of text with selenium, when all of the table rows have the same class

Tags: python, selenium

Just a quick question, I want to scrape the data on [this](http://isyslab.info/NeuroPep/search_info?pepNum=NP00003) page using python and selenium.

The below script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import time
import sys


options = Options()
options.binary_location=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path='/mnt/c/Users/kela/Desktop/selenium/chromedriver.exe')
for i in range(4):
        driver.get('http://isyslab.info/NeuroPep/search_info?pepNum=NP0000' + str(i))
#       element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[id=pmid]')
#       pmid = element.text

        element2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[id=content]')
        print(element2.text)
        print('**')
```

Will print the output (shortened for here):

```
NPID NP00003
Name C-terminal peptide (By similarity)
Organism Mus musculus
NCBI Taxa ID 10090
Tissue Specificity
Family 7B2
UniProt ID 7B2_MOUSE
Length 13
Modification NA
Gene Ontology
GO ID GO Term Definition
Evidence
GO:0005576 Cellular Component extracellular region IEA
GO:0030141 Cellular Component secretory granule ISS
GO:0004857 Molecular Function enzyme inhibitor activity IDA
GO:0051082 Molecular Function unfolded protein binding ISS
GO:0006886 Biological Process intracellular protein transport IDA
GO:0043086 Biological Process negative regulation of catalytic activity IDA
GO:0007218 Biological Process neuropeptide signaling pathway IEA
GO:0016486 Biological Process peptide hormone processing IDA
GO:0046883 Biological Process regulation of hormone secretion IDA
Sequence SVPHFSEEEK[10]EAE
Properties View
Structure NA
Reference NA
**
```

I DON'T want to scrape certain rows; specifically, I don't want (1) tissue specificity, (2) family, (3) gene ontology, (4) properties or (5) structure, (6) length

Or to put it another way, I ONLY want (1) NPID, (2) name, (3) organism, (4) NCBI Taxa ID, (5) UniProt, (6) Modification, (7) Reference.

The source HTML of the page I want to scrape is here:

[image]

So you can see, there's no specific tag (e.g. ID=XXX) that I can use to separate the rows I want from the rows I don't want; they all have the same class of title etc.

Can someone show me an example of how to pull out a specific row (e.g. how to pull out 'NP0003') from the table based on finding one of the specific rows I want (and then I can do the same for the rest?)

Edit 1: Adding a screenshot of an example row to be extracted, based on comment below:

[image]

Comment: get all rows and later filter it - if you know it is in third row then slice data `rows[2]`

Comment: that would be ideal, except when i checked 'print(type(element2.text))' it's a string (unsurprising since it's .text) and not a table, so then I'm not sure how to slice the data.

Comment: (and then print element2 without the .text is a webelement), so I'm unsure of how to extract all of the info, into an object type that 'rows[2]' would work with.

Comment: use `find_elements_...` with char **s** in word `elements` to find all elements - ie. all `<tr>` - and then you will have list and you can use `[2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding elements using xpath is provides more flexibility in this case. try this solution,

```
for i in range(4):
    print(i+1)
    driver.get('http://isyslab.info/NeuroPep/search_info?pepNum=NP0000' + str(i+1))
    time.sleep(3)
    NPID = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody/tr/td[contains(.,'NPID')]/following::td[1]")
    print(NPID.text)
    print('**')
```

Comment: Thanks, I got an error saying that that element doesn't exist (selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//tbody/tr/td[contains(.,'NPID')]/following::td/text()"})

Comment: It is possible that table is within a iframe. please check for tag iframe. if it so, then you will have to switch to that iframe and then try this xpath.

Comment: thanks, i've added a screenshot to show, there doesn't seem to be an iframe tag, but i'm wondering is the line 'input type='hidden'' affecting this line of code from working properly?

Comment: I just updated the answer. You will have find the rows using the text on the row and locate the following sibiling to get text.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I still get the same error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//tbody/tr/td[contains(.,'NPID')]/following::td[1]"}

Comment: The for loop was incorrect. The variable 'i' starts with 0, not 1. See the updated answer. I also added some wait time before scraping. This is working in my local.